# Ubuntu 12.04 wlan not running (Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24))

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, intel-wireless

I just installed 12.04.2, and got the latest updates. 
Network with cable ethernet ist running fine, but wlan never did so.

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

`ifconfig` shows only "eth0" and "lo", there is no wlan mentioned.
My notebook is a Asus BV53.

Comment: try: ifconfig -a

Comment: ok, I did. There is a wlan wit "-a", but no ip signed to it. I have the wlan router with dhcp standig 2m away. Besides, in the network manager i cant move the blue switch to turn on wlan.
Thx so far.

Comment: ok, try the commands listed here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1425727 you might need to enable OPEN authentication at first

Comment: @infact - please summarise the link into an answer that you can then work on to help out resolving the question being posed.

Comment: Done. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to disable N as that cause issues in iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 
But the best result I could get so far was to install ndiswrapper and the windoss driver trough it.

Comment: ok,  I did. There is a wlan wit "-a", but no ip signed to it. I have the wlan router with dhcp standig 2m away. Besides, in the network manager i cant move the blue switch to turn on wlan.

Comment: Your module (driver) is not loaded. That's why the interface isn't there. Did you install ndiswrapper? Did you load the driver by using start menu windows drivers and then load the windows driver unpacked from the disk? You might need to install or at least unpack the driver first in windows if wine does not do it.