# Problem using wifi

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 and my machine is dell inspiron 1420. Can anybody suggest me that how to enable my wifi because in my network connections there is no list of wifi networks and even my the system is not showing that wifi is turned on !!

Comment: Also try the suggestions listed here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286868/ubuntu-12-04-wlan-not-running-intel-corporation-centrino-advanced-n-6235-rev-2

Answer (score 0):

I believe that will be solved by ndiswrapper :) http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=916235